# env-cmd command is not fetching environment variables in Nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, environment-variables, bundling-and-minification, env-cmd

I am trying to use env-cmd to load environment variables in next js

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "env-cmd -f .env.build next dev -p 3006",
"build": "env-cmd -f .env.build next build",
"start": "next start -p 3006",
"lint": "next lint",
}
```

However, it is unable to load the environment variables in the code

```
const programUrl  = process.env[`PROGRAM_URL`] as string;
```

This line is running on the browser and the value is undefined, the .env.build has that particular environment variable.

How could this be debugged ?

Comment: You need to use 'NEXT_PUBLIC_' prefix on your variables